# Bootstrap button inside input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make it so that it appears nicely after input page with same height?

```
<div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <button class="input-group-addon" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
</div>
```

Here is code http://jsfiddle.net/6mcxdjdr/ The first one is original input-group, the second one is something what I am trying to have

Comment: there is also a class called input-group-btn, [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you follow [bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#button-addons):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is not applicable if using version 4+

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 4 provides the classes `input-group-prepend` and `input-group-append` that allows the effect of button inside input.

Below the snippet for a **left** aligned button inside input-group (class `input-group-prepend`):

```css
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Prepended button</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">  
</div>
```

And the snippet for a **right** aligned button inside input-group (class `input-group-append`):

```css
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">  
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution, using a little CSS to position the button to the right of the input field by adding `position: absolute` and a `z-index`:

```
button.input-group-addon {
  position: absolute;
  right: -38px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 34px;
  width: 38px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6mcxdjdr/1/

Another idea is to manipulate the form submit with javascript, so you dont have to create your own button but submit the form by clicking on the bootstrap span. This could be done by 
`$('.input-group-addon').click(function(){ $('#myform').submit(); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way

```
 <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </span><span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

.search-input {
  border-right: 0;
}

.input-group-addon {
  background: white;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

.input-group-addon:last-child {
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.input-group-addon{
width:50px;  
position:absolute;
margin-left:196px;
height:34px;
}
.input-group-addon > i{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, I had to override some css...

(Bootstrap 4 Beta 2)

Html

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="search..." />
        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-btn bg-white">
            <button class="btn px-2" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

And here's the css

```
#app-search .input-group-addon-btn {
    padding: 0;

    button {
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```